# Choosing a value in a drop down box based on database query

Tags: php, html, forms, drop-down-menu

I basically need to create a value by default for a drop down menu on a PHP page that will use the value previously selected and stored in the database.

For example, lets just say I have the value '3' stored in a database column. I want to use this number as the default value for a drop down menu where the `<option value = "3">Good</option>`. Is there a simple solution to this problem?

Or do i literally need to loop through the values until it makes a value?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually do this

```
<?php
    $sel = 'selected="selected"';
    $current_whatever = 5;
?>

<option name="whatever">
    <?php foreach($list as $listItem): ?>
        <option value="<?=$listItem->id?>" <?=($listItem->id == $current_whatever)?$sel:''?>><?=$listItem->name?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</option>
```

I'm using an inline if statement to check each one :) Looks **reasonably** tidy.

*Assuming you're using database objects, you get the idea if you're not though :)*

Comment: Ternary operator is the technical name if anyone needs to do research on it. Unfortunately in most cases they result in hard to read code. This looks like a viable solution though if you are generating your list of options which seems to make the most sense.

Comment: Well I am using PDO if thats what you mean? Yeah this makes sense, It just for an edit page so it displays what has already been chosen. Seems a better option than just leaving it.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php foreach($options as $key=>$option){?>
<option value='<?=$key?>' <? echo $key==$selected?"SELECTED":"";?> ><?=$option?></option>
<? }?>
```